# CCButton not calling method

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

In my Cocos2d game I am adding a pause button to the CCScene. The pause button is a CCButton. The problem is that when my button is pressed the action isn't called. I have tested the button on the main menu and it work fine. I tried using control.block = ^(id sender) and it didn't work either. I am calling addPauseButton method in the init method. I'm wondering if the problem has to do with the physics node.

```
-(void)addPauseButton
{
    CCSpriteFrame *pauseNormalImage = [CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:@"pause.png"];
    CCSpriteFrame *pauseHighlightedImage  = [CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:@"pause_selected.png"];
    CCButton *btnPause = [CCButton buttonWithTitle:nil
                                       spriteFrame:pauseNormalImage
                            highlightedSpriteFrame:pauseHighlightedImage
                               disabledSpriteFrame:nil];

    btnPause.positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
    btnPause.position = ccp(0.85f, 0.85f);
    [btnPause setTarget:self selector:@selector(onbtnPauseTapped:)];

    [self addChild:btnPause z:10000]; 
}


- (void)onbtnPauseTapped:(id)sender
{
     NSLog(@"Working?");

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same issue a while ago and couldn't figure it. The problem was a `UIGestureRecognizer` preventing the user touch being sent up the responder chain. Check your code to see if you are using a `UIGestureRecognizer`. I also recommend reading the Apple documentation for [UIGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/).